# How to invalidate session at server side after certain time, if client is continuously making the request after a certain timeout

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

Hi i have a requirement for session time out 
i have already set the session timeout property in my server

```
    <session-timeout> 30</session-timeout>
```

i am refreshing a part of my webpage at every 10 seconds,So the problem is the session never expires at server side irrespective of user interaction.So what is the best way to implement this scenario eitherthrough javascript or through server side.

Comment: Perhaps an interceptor? Intercept all of the requests and note how long it's been since something other than your update method was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval overrides the session timeout entry in web.xml

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(TIME_IN_SECONDS)
```